# How to remove some identical objects in array(js)?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects(like this)

```
[
{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316}
{teamName: 'first', playerId: 315}
{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316}
{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316}
{teamName: 'second', playerId: 315}
{teamName: 'second', playerId: 318}
{teamName: 'third', playerId: 318}
{teamName: 'third', playerId: 316}
]
```

And I need to write a function which removes some identical objects in array, and the output should be like this:

```
[
{teamName: 'first', playerId: 315}
{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316}
{teamName: 'second', playerId: 315}
{teamName: 'second', playerId: 318}
{teamName: 'third', playerId: 318}
{teamName: 'third', playerId: 316}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could convert this to a structure `{[teamName]: SetOfPlayerIds}` and convert it back to your structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For really large arrays, you could convert this to a structure `{[teamName]: SetOfPlayerIds}` and convert it back to your structure. This approach has a better performance (O(n log n)) than comparing each element with each other (O(n²)).

```js
const data = [{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316},{teamName: 'first', playerId: 315},{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316},{teamName: 'first', playerId: 316},{teamName: 'second', playerId: 315},{teamName: 'second', playerId: 318},{teamName: 'third', playerId: 318},{teamName: 'third', playerId: 316}];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, { teamName, playerId }) => {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(teamName)) acc[teamName] = new Set();
  acc[teamName].add(playerId);
  return acc;
}, {})).flatMap(([teamName, playerIds]) => Array.from(playerIds).map(playerId => ({ teamName, playerId })));

console.log(result);
```